# Separating the elements of arraylist

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` that contains a *messageId*, then a `-`, then a *username*.
Example : `E123-sam`

I want to divide each element of my `List` such that the part before the `-` goes to one `ArrayList` and the part after that goes to an other `ArrayList`.

How can I do it?

Comment: [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: @MarounMaroun Could you please write a line of code to do it ?

Comment: Please try yourself first, if you fail post your attempts and we'll help you.

Comment: You need to make array then iterate your arrayList() so you will get separate array element then using String.split("-") you will get both part in your string array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have these `ArrayList`s:

```
List<String> allStrings;
// ... initialization and filling of 'allStrings'
List<String> messageIDs = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

you can loop through elements of the `ArrayList` and use [`String#split(delimiter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to separate   the string based in the `delimiter`:

```
for (String s : allStrings) {
    String[] parts = s.split("-");
    messageIDs.add(parts[0]);
    userNames.add(parts[1]);
}
```

**Note:** This will work if all the strings in `allStrings` follows the pattern `"something-something"`. If not, then you can check if the length of `parts` is correct before accessing its elements, otherwise you will get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I don't get the donnvote on this. While it is not ideal to write code for people who obviously simply need to find a library function and/or read on loops and collections, this is the right solution that also teaches the poor guy something. Or not?

Comment: I was the downvoter, sorry I didn't mention that. I tend to downvote **ready full** answers to questions that doesn't demonstrate minimal research efforts. This time I'll remove my downvote because of the good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Java 8, you could do:

```
List<String> listOfIds = original.stream().map(e -> e.split("-")[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> listOfUsernames = original.stream().map(e -> e.split("-")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```